# Make a label a global element

Tags: xcode, swift4

I have some code to make global variables that I can use to access variables across multiple .swift files. It looks like this:

```
struct globalValues { 
   static var test:Double = 1
}
```

And then I call it using

```
globalValues.test = 2
```

Can I do something similar to an @IBOutlet label?

Comment: Don't rely on UI (View part). Instead, update the value of "globalValue" when the label change, rely on the model. Why? Because an IBOutlet might not be initialized when you want to read it elsewhere, or simply removed from memory.

Comment: you might use a computed property to capture @IBOutlet assignment and then assign it to a weak global variable

Comment: Are you trying to update labels in different view controllers? The short answer is 'no' you can't because IBOutlets can only exist in dynamic instances and certainly not guaranteed to exist for the lifetime of an application. Have a look at Notifications and Observers.

Answer (score 0):

A label cannot be global because it belongs only to one view controller. Moreover, it is very wrong to talk directly to a label (e.g. to read its text, or even worse to write to its text) from outside the view controller that owns it. Only a view controller should be in any way aware of its views as views.

Instead, your other code needs to figure out how to get a *reference* to the view controller that has the label. And then the view controller must have *accessor functions* or *public properties* that allow other code to talk to it about the *data* underlying the label in a coherent manner. If the view controller wants to respond by changing the label in some way, that is its business.